# how to customise the ouput results of a .bat file with multiple commands within it to a single txt file

Tags: batch-file

Hi I need to have the results of this bat file to be in a single .txt or .csv file with the relevant headings

the file runs perfectly but I can only get it to make any sense if I output to individual files.
any help or advice will be gratefully received.

```
@echo off

MD\"PC Details"
hostname>>C:\"PC Details"\PC_HostName.txt
wmic csproduct get name >>C:\"PC Details"\Model.txt
wmic bios get serialnumber >>C:\"PC Details"\PC_SerialNo.txt
wmic diskdrive get model >>C:\"PC Details"\HDD.txt
wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber >>C:\"PC Details"\HDD_SerialNo.txt

end
```

Comment: Why can't you redirect the output of each line to the same file?

Comment: the formatting is none existing, and I don't know how to make headers

Comment: WMIC has a lot of output formatting options. Try `wmic csproduct get name /format:csv` to see what I mean. [Here](http://www.vanstechelman.eu/windows/wmic/output_formats) is a list of them.

Comment: Also `wmic csproduct get name /value` may give you a better output

Comment: I guess the key here is, What do you want the output to look like? Edit your post and show required output.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output of each line to the same file and put separators or headers between sections of the output file using `ECHO`.

Something like this...

```
@echo off

MD\"PC Details"
ECHO --- HOSTNAME SECTION>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
hostname>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
ECHO ---------------------------------------------->>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
ECHO --- WMIC CSPRODUCT SECTION>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
wmic csproduct get name>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
ECHO ---------------------------------------------->>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
ECHO --- WMIC BIOS SECTION>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
wmic bios get serialnumber>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
ECHO ---------------------------------------------->>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
ECHO --- WMIC DISKDRIVE SECTION>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
wmic diskdrive get model>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
ECHO ---------------------------------------------->>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
ECHO --- WMIC PHYSICALMEDIA SECTION>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber>>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
ECHO ---------------------------------------------->>"C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this. Change the "YOUR_TITLE" to the title you chose.

```
@echo off
set outputfile="C:\PC Details\Details.txt"
MD\"PC Details"
echo YOUR_TITLE>>%outputfile%
hostname>>%outputfile%
echo YOUR_TITLE>>%outputfile%
wmic csproduct get name>>%outputfile%
echo YOUR_TITLE>>%outputfile%
wmic bios get serialnumber>>%outputfile%
echo YOUR_TITLE>>%outputfile%
wmic diskdrive get model>>%outputfile%
echo YOUR_TITLE>>%outputfile%
wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber>>%outputfile%
goto :eof
```

Comment: many thanks for your advice so far, I feel like I am now going in the right direction, okay the title headings are working in list but the results from the commands are not, maybe I am missing something obvious?

Comment: use quotes around `set outputfile`. Right now, it's just seeing `C:\PC`

Comment: Also wmic csproduct get name /value may give you a better output –  Stephan 17 hours ago :  this is definitely heading to what I need, I now have a couple more questions if I can ask here, : Ineed to get the hostname of the machine and no matter what I do I cannot get it to do it (as you have have already guessed I am no expert at all with bat files) also I am getting two extr serial number lines which are empty, any ideas?

Comment: You should put these in a separate question but for a host name you would use Line1: set host=%COMPUTERNAME% Line2: echo %host%

Comment: many thanks to all who have put forward your suggestions I think I am finaly there.: apart from the hostname spacing output format i have what i need this is my finished bat file:                     @echo off

MD\"PC Details"
wmic nicconfig get DNSHostName >>C:\"PC Details"\PC_Details.txt
wmic csproduct get name/value >>C:\"PC Details"\PC_Details.txt
wmic bios get serialnumber/value >>C:\"PC Details"\PC_Details.txt
wmic diskdrive get model/value >>C:\"PC Details"\PC_Details.txt
wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber/value >>C:\"PC Details"\PC_Details.txt

end